# multiline regular expression matches

Tags: regex

currently trying to get a regex that can perform multiline matching. However, I would like the "*2020-07-06T16:06:57-04:00 k8s-node03 k8s_inventory[28257]*" to be ignored in the matches. For example:

```
Match group 1: INFO  A. Line 1
Match group 2: INFO  B. Line 1 
                     B. Line 2
                     B. Line 3
Match group 3: C. Line 1
```

Sample log:

```
2020-07-06T16:06:57-04:00 k8s-node03 k8s_inventory[28257] 06-07-2020 16:06:57.535 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  A. Line 1
2020-07-06T16:06:57-04:00 k8s-node03 k8s_inventory[28257] 06-07-2020 16:06:57.539 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  B. Line 1
2020-07-06T16:06:57-04:00 k8s-node03 k8s_inventory[28257] B. Line 2
2020-07-06T16:06:57-04:00 k8s-node03 k8s_inventory[28257] B. Line 3
2020-07-06T16:06:57-04:00 k8s-node03 k8s_inventory[28257] 06-07-2020 16:06:57.548 [SpringContextShutdownHook] C. Line 1
```

A regex I created places everything in different match groups.

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2} \S+ \S+ (?<rawlog>.*)$
```

-- but i am trying to figure out how to get the 'B' matches in the same match group. Is this possible /w regex?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide details about which tool or platform you are using, as instructed in the [Stack Overfow `regex` tag info page.](/tags/regex/info)

Comment: @Mandy8055 This regex works as expected :)

Comment: just a quick question -- in this regex, it is looking for the hard coded values of A. , B. , or C.  ... would it be possible to have it look for any value ?

Comment: im currently trying to implement this regex into fluentd which uses ruby syntax

Comment: for example, in this case: https://regex101.com/r/IUkGLX/4 were not able to capture sample text. is this something that can be easily captured?

edit: ive made an edit to the regex: https://regex101.com/r/IUkGLX/5 but somehwat achieves this ... ill play around and see that i can get :)

Comment: But you said the the pattern will be common throughout. If you'll change the pattern then it will be problem. Okay; please let me know till what point the pattern won't change. Check [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/IUkGLX/6) once

Comment: Just to provide some context -- im currently trying to grab stack traces from container logs. I've pasted some sample logs here: https://regex101.com/r/IUkGLX/11 . As you can see -- each new log line begins with the date time stamp but some logs are on a new line (e.g. "Host: localhost:8080#015" ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2} \S+ \S+ (?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3} \[[^][]*\](?: [A-Z]{2,}\s+)?)?(A\..+)|(B\..+)|(C\..+)$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Matches start and end of the line respectively.
- **`(A\..*)`** - Represents the first capturing group capturing everything after `A.` till the end.
- **`|`** - Represents alternation.
- **`(B\..*)`** - Represents the second capturing group capturing everything after `B.` till the end.
- **`(C\..*)`** - Represents the third capturing group capturing everything after `C.` till the end. If you want them to be dynamic simply use `[A-Z]\.`.

Thanks to [@thefourthbird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) for suggesting this valuable regex.

#### Regex Demo

Comment: @Mandy8055, in your output -- there are five match groups. I would like for there to be three match groups. Editing the op, Sorry if there was any confusion --

Comment: No; there is only one match group namely; `group 1`. Please do have a look on the group number.

Comment: Ah - my mistake -- misread. in any case, would it be possible to seperate the A, B, and C matches? In this isntance, all of them are aggregated into a single group ~~

Comment: Yep, thats what I've been trying to get :)